# Как удалить из словаря и из вложенных словарей на всех уровнях элементы, значения которых являются None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как удалить из словаря элементы, значения которых является `None`? Словарь извлекается из json- строки.

Исходный словарь может содержать вложенные словари, из которых опять же надо удалить элементы, значения которых является `None`. И во вложенных словарях могут быть словари, с которыми надо проделать то же самое. И т.д.

Пример. 
Пусть у нас есть следующий словарь:

```
{  
   "chat_id":234,
   "disable_notification": None,
   "disable_web_page_preview": None,
   "parse_mode": None,
   "reply_markup":{  
      "inline_keyboard":[  
         [  
            {  
               "callback_data": None,
               "callback_game": None,
               "pay": None,
               "switch_inline_query": None,
               "switch_inline_query_current_chat": None,
               "text":"add",
               "url": None
            },
            {  
               "callback_data": None,
               "callback_game": None,
               "pay": None,
               "switch_inline_query": None,
               "switch_inline_query_current_chat": None,
               "text":"sub",
               "url": None
            }
         ]
      ]
   },
   "reply_to_message_id": None,
   "text":"45456546"
}
```

Должен получиться в результате следующий словарь:

```
{  
   "chat_id":234,
   "reply_markup": {  
      "inline_keyboard":[  
         [  
            {  
               "text":"add",
            },
            {  
               "text":"sub",
            }
         ]
      ]
   },
   "text":"45456546"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dict_trim(elem):
    if isinstance(elem, dict):
        return {k: dict_trim(v)
                for (k, v) in elem.items()
                if v is not None
                }
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        return [dict_trim(item) for item in elem]
    return elem

print(dict_trim(ваш_словарь))
```